# Why have astronauts had to take Soyuz capsules "out for a spin" on 15 separate occasions? (move from one Soyuz port to another)

Tags: iss, mission-design, soyuz-spacecraft, docking-port

NASA News item [Space Station Crew to Relocate Soyuz to Make Room for New Crewmates](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/space-station-crew-to-relocate-soyuz-to-make-room-for-new-crewmates) says:

> Three residents of the International Space Station will take a spin around their orbital neighborhood in the Soyuz MS-17 on Friday, March 19, relocating the spacecraft to prepare for the arrival of the next set of crew members. Live coverage on NASA Television, the NASA app, and the agency’s website will begin at 12:15 p.m. EDT.
>
> Expedition 64 Flight Engineer Kate Rubins of NASA and Commander Sergey Ryzhikov and Sergey Kud-Sverchkov, both of the Russian Space Agency Roscosmos, will undock from the Earth-facing port of the station’s Rassvet module at 12:38 p.m. and dock again at the space-facing Poisk docking port at 1:07 p.m.
>
> The relocation will free up the Rassvet port for the docking of another Soyuz vehicle, designated Soyuz MS-18, which will carry three Expedition 65 crew members to the station next month. NASA’s Mark Vande Hei and Roscosmos’ Oleg Novitsky and Pyotr Dubrov are scheduled to launch to the station Friday, April 9, from the Baikonur Cosmodrome in Kazakhstan.
>
> **This will be the 15th overall Soyuz port relocation and the first since August 2019.**

That last sentence already answers the first draft of my question. but 15 times surprises me, so I'll ask instead:

**Question:** What are the reasons that astronauts have had to take Soyuz capsules "out for a spin" on 15 occasions? Is there generally a typical set of circumstances that requires moving a capsule from one Soyuz port to another, or are the reasons disparate?

Comment: Related: [Why will the Soyuz MS-17 be relocated on the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46789/29286)

Comment: See answer by Robert Frost here https://www.quora.com/Why-do-they-have-to-move-the-Soyuz-spacecraft-from-one-docking-port-to-another-at-the-ISS-when-a-new-one-comes-in

Comment: You gotta run the engine for 20 minutes or so every couple of weeks to keep the batteries charged up ;)

Comment: related: [Why were three astronauts packed tightly into a Soyuz capsule just to move it from one docking port to the other?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50908/12102)